# Unable to access tables in sql server using oracle dblink

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I have created a Heterogeneous  connection between oracle and sql server. and tested with below query,

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables@SQLSERVER;
```

Then I have created a new Database in SQL server called "TESTCONNECTION" and created a table called "dbo.TEST". After that I changed the default database of DSN to "TESTCONNECTION". But below query fail with following error message.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TEST@SQLSERVER;
```

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name
>   'DBO.TEST'. {42S02,NativeErr = 208}[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   {42000,NativeErr = 8180

}

How to overcome this error and access tables created under "TESTCONNECTION".

Comment: You'll probably need to prefix the database name as well. `TESTCONNECTION.dbo.Test`

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I have already tried SELECT * FROM "TESTCONNECTION.dbo.Test"@SQLSERVER; But got same error message

Comment: Did you put the table name between quotes (`SELECT * FROM "dbo.TEST"@SQLSERVER;`)? Oracle SQL is not case sensitive by default.

Comment: @Marco But got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential cause could be that the default database listed for the user account being used to connect to SQL Server is pointed to the wrong database.  Adjust this on the SQL Server side and see if that resolves your issue.

[image]

Comment: Default database is already configured to TESTCONNECTION database

Comment: @User12345 I just have a nagging feeling you're not connecting to the target database you think you are.  I guess you can confirm by rerunning the statement that worked against `sys.tables` and see if the *new* table appears in the list or not.

Comment: I can able to access the database after restrating sql server.